# Lookup field for parliamentary constituency

Tags: extension

Hello I would like to have the ability to lookup the parliamentary constituency of a person when they put in the postcode. The data should return into a custom field. The data source would need to be an external database (probably sql) I am aware that there is regional lookup extension (does it work on 4.7?) and there is county lookup (can that be tweaked to lookup a different field). Does anyone have any views on this? Are there other extensions I'm not aware of?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This service would be one option: https://mapit.mysociety.org/

Answer (score 1):

For interest's sake in the end I went with a solution that sat outside civicrm (for now). I used PHP to look up and return the MP name from a sql table which I created by uploading data from http://www.list-logic.co.uk/lists/parliamentary-constituencies/list-of-uk-constituencies.html

The list of people who submitted the form are being manually uploaded into civicrm daily.